# About the condition such that $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ is the $n$-th power of an integer for every integer $x$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

> **Question**  : Is the following true for any $n\ge 2\in\mathbb N$?
>
> Letting $a_n, a_{n-1}, \cdots, a_1,a_0\in\mathbb R$ be constants, the necessary and sufficient condition for $a_n, a_{n-1}, \cdots, a_1,a_0$ such that $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\ (\star)$ is the $n$-th power of an integer for **every** integer $x$ is that each of $a_n, a_0$ is the $n$-th power of an integer and $D_n=0$ where $D_n$ is the discriminant of $(\star)=0$.
>
> Note that $D_n={a_0}^{2(n-1)}\left\{\Pi_{i\lt j}({\alpha}_i-{\alpha}_j)\right\}^2$ where ${\alpha}_1,\cdots,{\alpha}_n$ are the $n$ roots, counted with multiplicity, of $(\star)=0$. For example, $D_2={a_1}^2-4a_2a_0, D_3=-4a_3{a_1}^3-27{a_3}^2{a_0}^2-4{a_2}^3a_0+{a_2}^2{a_1}^2+18a_3a_2a_1a_0.$

**Motivation** : I've known that this is true for $n=2$. Also, this seems true for $n=3$. However, I'm facing difficulty for $n$ in general. Can anyone help?

**Proof for $n=2$** : Let $ax^2+bx+c=\{f(x)\}^2$ where $f(x)$ is a non-negative integer.

$(1)$ The $a=0$ case : $b=0$ is necessary for that $bx+c\ge0$ for any integer $x$. Then, we can write $c=k^2$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

$(2)$ The $a\not=0$ case : Since $a+\frac bx+\frac{c}{x^2}=\left\{\frac{f(x)}{x}\right\}^2\ (f(x)\ge0)$, we get $a\gt0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\sqrt a$. Also, since
$$\{f(x+1)\}^2-\{f(x)\}^2=a(2x+1)+b,$$
$$\frac{f(x+1)+f(x)}{x}\cdot\{f(x+1)-f(x)\}=a\left(2+\frac 1x\right)+\frac bx,$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+1)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+1)}{x+1}\cdot\frac{x+1}{x}=\sqrt a,$$
we get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\{f(x+1)-f(x)\}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left\{a\left(2+\frac 1x\right)+\frac bx\right\}/\left\{\frac{f(x+1)}{x}+\frac{f(x)}{x}\right\}=\frac{2a}{2\sqrt a}=\sqrt a.$$
Since $f(x+1)-f(x)$ is an integer, $\sqrt a$ is an integer. Hence, we can write $\sqrt a=l$ where $l\in\mathbb N$. Since
$$l^2x^2+bx+c=\{f(x)\}^2,$$
$$bx+c=\{f(x)+lx\}\{f(x)-lx\},$$
$$b+\frac cx=\left\{\frac{f(x)}{x}+l\right\}\cdot\{f(x)-lx\},$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}+l=\sqrt a+l=2l,$$
we get $\lim_{x\to\infty}\{f(x)-lx\}=\frac{b}{2l}.$ Since $f(x)-lx$ is an integer, we can write $\frac{b}{2l}=k$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$. Hence, we get $b=2kl$. Hence, we get
$$l^2x^2+2klx+c=\{f(x)\}^2,$$
$$(lx+k)^2+c-k^2=\{f(x)\}^2,$$
$$\{f(x)+lx+k\}\{f(x)-lx-k\}=c-k^2.$$
Since it is obvious that $c$ is an integer, if $c-k^2\not=0$, then the number of pairs $f(x),lx$ which satisfy this is finite, which is a contradiction. Hence, $c-k^2=0$ leads $c=k^2$.

On the other hand, if $a=l^2, b=2lk, c=k^2\ (l\in\mathbb N, k\in\mathbb Z)$, then we get $ax^2+bx+c=(lx+k)^2.$

Hence, we now know the answer is that each of $a, c$ is a square number and $b^2-4ac=0$ as desired.

Comment: This condition is not sufficient. Consider $g(x) = (x+8)^2 (8x+1) = 8 x^3 + 129 x^2 + 528 x + 64$: the cubic and constant terms are cubes and the discriminant is $0$ (because it has a double root), but $g(2) = 10^2 \times 17$ is not a cube. A much more reasonable conjecture is that $f(x)$ is an $n$-th power for every $x$ if and only if $f(x) = g(x)^n$ for some polynomial $g(x)$.

Comment: @David, I'm pretty sure your conjecture is a theorem, though I'm not sure where to find it.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Thank you very much for pointing it out.